# Konjunktiv 2 der Vergangenheit von Modalverben

Tags: grammatical-case, subjunctive, modal-verb

Laut meinem Buch, gibt es nur eine Form des Konjunktivs 2 der Vergangenheit, und es ist dieselbe für Präteritum und Perfekt.

Zum Beispiel, der Satz, „Sie klingelten“ wird zu „Sie hätten geklingelt“.

Warum wird der Satz „**Sie wollten reden**“, zu „**Sie hätten reden wollen**“, und nicht zu „**Sie hätten reden gewollt**“?

Laut Anweisungen bildet man Konjunktiv 2 der Vergangenheit mit Hilfsverben wäre/hätte + Perfekt form von das Verb.